# iOS 8 - Map keeps reanimating back to user location

Tags: ios, mapkit

this question has been stumping me for a while: my map, when I run it on my iOS device, has started to 'boomerang' back to the user's location whenever I scroll to look at a different pin I recently dropped. It, strangely, has only begun doing this recently.

Here's my code for that:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.searchBar.delegate = self;
   self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
   self.locationManager.delegate = self;

   if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector
     (requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
     mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
   }
   [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark cllocation delegate methods
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:
(NSArray *)locations
{
NSLog(@"location info object=%@",[locations lastObject]);
[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Success"   
 message:@"Location      
received" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
}
```

Any ideas on how I can handle the user location problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code says:

```
 mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

That means that map view is *tracking* the user location. It wants to keep showing it. If you want the map view to stop doing that, stop tracking the user location.

Typically, you'll adjust the MKUserTrackingMode. The simplest way to do *that*, and to let the user do it, is to provide an MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem.

Also, make sure that you are not setting the map region somewhere else. Setting the map region can fight against scrolling the map if you're not careful.

Comment: Matt's answer is correct, the MapView is tracking the user's location. The missing part is how to stop this. In order to stop it from tracking the user's location, try to set showsUserLocation to NO when you tell your locationManager to stopUpdatingLocation. Try that and see what happens.

Comment: Is this answer correct?  `showsUserLocation` simply controls whether the current location annotation is shown.  If `userTrackingMode` is set to `MKUserTrackingModeNone` then then map shouldn't zoom to  the user

Comment: @Paulw11 Did you actually _read_ my answer? That's what I said: "Typically, you'll adjust the MKUserTrackingMode." The problem is that the user tracking mode is _not_ `MKUserTrackingModeNone`. It's `MKUserTrackingModeFollow`. Hence, it follows.

Comment: You said " mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
That means that map view is tracking the user location." which implies that this is the OP's problem - but this setting on its own does not cause the focus of the map view to change, which is the problem at hand. You discuss providing a tracking mode button, but don't explicitly reference the property or value likely to be at issue.  Perhaps you assumed that the OP can read the documentation on this.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm with you. It's true that I'm making some guesses as to what else might be going on in the OP's code. And yes, it is certainly true that my goal is to point the OP in what might the right direction - which, based on the information we have, is all we can do.

Comment: Added a button with 'find my location' - not what I was originally looking for, but it worked better for me.